# Coldfusion CSV to Spreadsheet

Tags: csv, coldfusion, cfspreadsheet, coldfusion-2018

I have a few processes that utilize the CFSpreadsheet tag to import and then manipulate Excel data.  This works great for .XLS & .XLSX files, however, it doesn't work if the data is sent as a .CSV file since CFSpreadsheet apparently was never updated to import .CSV files.  At the end of the day I just want a *simple* pre-processor that takes a .CSV file and re-writes it as an .XLSX file so that my other process can take it from there.

My environment is the developer edition of Coldfusion 2018 and I've tried importing the data manually (which can work if I know all of the column definitions---but I won't always know that).  My latest attempt has been with Ben Nadel's CSVToArray function ( https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2041-update-parsing-csv-data-files-in-coldfusion-with-csvtoarray.htm ) which works---I can easily get the .CSV file into an array---but I can't figure out how to go from that array to something like a query that I can write a spreadsheet with using CFSpreadsheet.

Here's an EXAMPLE:

```
<!--- This include is the function from Ben Nadel referenced above --->
<cfinclude template="Function_CSVtoArray.cfm"> 

<cfset result = csvToArray(file="TEST_File.csv") />

<cfdump var="#result#" label="TESTING">

<!--- *** The above WORKS up to this point ***--->

<!--- Create a new query. --->
<cfset qPartsTwo = QueryNew( "" ) />

<!--- Loop over keys in the struct. --->
<cfloop index="strKey" list="#StructKeyList(result)#" delimiters=",">

<!--- Add column to new query with default values. --->
<cfset QueryAddColumn(qPartsTwo,strKey,"VARCHAR",objParts[strKey]) />

</cfloop>

<!--- This code FAILS with a "You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members" error message --->
```

I'd like to end up at something like this (although right now "result" is an array of some kind and not a query):

```
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="<my path>\TEST.xlsx" query="result">
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: I think `<cfspreadsheet>` can read a CSV directory into a query. This might end up being a two step operation. See https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfspreadsheet.html

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Well that was my first try way back when but the CFSpreadsheet tag fails when you try to read a CSV file.  It apparently can *write* a CSV file but not *read* one (which I know makes zero sense).

Comment: Running this tag:  <cfspreadsheet action="read" src="<my path>\TEST.csv" format="csv" name="ExcelQ"> throws the error "An error occurred while reading the Excel: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream."

Comment: Looks like you are trying to build the query up column by column. Consider row by row.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean with "row by row" in the context of my example?  I'm not really sure what you mean and that code was just another example from somewhere else online.

Comment: Honestly, Apache POI is bundled with CF, so why not use it directly? `createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser")`

Comment: So that looks really useful, but it seems to do pretty much what the CSVToArray function does?  So I'm still not sure how to go from that (i.e. reading/parsing an CSV file) to outputting an XLS file.  Do you have a short, simple example of that that you could provide?

Comment: I've also tried CSVToQuery (https://cflib.org/udf/CSVToQuery) but can't seem to figure out how to get that to either modify it to look at an actual CSV *file* OR to get it to look at the output of my data from CSVToArray.

Comment: Re: *You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable ...*  That's because the code is using `result` as if it were a structure. It's not, it's an array.  Assuming the file has headers, the column names will be the first element in the multi-dimensional array. With `result[ 1 ]` returning an array of the column names, and `result[1][1]` pointing to the first column, `result[1][2]` the second column, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your UDF returns a multi-dimensional array, *not* an array of structures. Instead of trying to coerce the array into a query object, try using [spreadsheet functions](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-by-category/spreadsheet-functions.html) to write the array data to an xlsx file.

**DEMO / Sample data**

```
result = [ ["First Name", "Last Name", "Address"]   
           , ["John", "Doe", "123 Anywhere Ave"]    
           , ["Mary", "Smith", "456 Somewhere Street"]  
           , ["Charles", "Doe", "789 Anywhere Court"]   
];
```

**Code:**

```
// create spreadsheet
xlsx = SpreadSheetNew("The Results", true);
// populate with array data
SpreadSheetAddRows( xlsx, result ); 
// save to file
SpreadSheetWrite( xlsx, "c:/path/to/test.xlsx", true );
```

.. or as [James A Mohler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1845869/james-a-mohler) suggested, you could also use [member functions](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/using-the-member-functions.html):

```
xlsx = SpreadSheetNew("The Results", true);
xlsx.addRows( result );
xlsx.write( "c:/path/to/test.xlsx", true );
```

Comment: You are amazing---THANK YOU!  That actually works perfectly and does EXACTLY what I want it to do (take any .CSV file and re-write it as an .XLSX file).

Comment: Here is the complete code for anyone else that would like it:

    <cfinclude template="Function_CSVtoArray.cfm">

    <cfset result = csvToArray(file="TEST.csv") />

    <cfscript>
     // create spreadsheet
     xlsx = SpreadSheetNew("The Results", true);
     // populate with array data
     SpreadSheetAddRows( xlsx, result ); 
     // save to file
     SpreadSheetWrite( xlsx, "c:\temp\TEST.xlsx", true );
    </cfscript>

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: I like that it goes straight from array if arrays to spreadsheet. I wonder if it can be done with spreadsheet member functions.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you could do something like this

```
<cfinclude template="Function_CSVtoArray.cfm"> 

<cfset result = csvToArray(file="TEST_File.csv") />

<cfdump var="#result#" label="TESTING">


<!--- setup the columns that you need --->
<cfset qPartsTwo = queryNew("id,name,amount","Integer,Varchar,Integer", result) />

<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="<my path>\TEST.xlsx" query="result">
```

`CSVToArray()` looks like it makes an array of structs.

Comment: I actually did try that as well early on.  It has the disadvantage that I would have to explicitly define every column (and there are multiple potential variations).  But then in testing it I'm getting the error message "The column name First Name is invalid. Column names must be valid variable names. They must start with a letter and can only include letters, numbers, and underscores" because the file has multi-word column names (e.g. "First Name")....

Comment: While convenient, `cfspreadsheet` is limited. Rather than jumping through hoops trying to make it work, it may be simpler to use spreadsheet functions. Loop through your array and populate each row. Then you could define whatever headers you want. If you absolutely must use `cfspreadsheet` with a query, you'll have to scrub the potential column names first, to remove any invalid characters

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an array of structures from CSVToArray.  Can you then use the ArrayOfStructuresToQuery function:  https://cflib.org/udf/ArrayOfStructuresToQuery

Comment: Yeah I found that early on in my troubleshooting but I get the same "You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members" error message.  Here's the code I'm running:

    <cfinclude template="Function_CSVtoArray.cfm">
    <cfinclude template="Function_ArrayOfStructuresToQuery.cfm">

    <cfset result = csvToArray(file="TEST.csv")>

    <CFSET resultQuery=ArrayOfStructuresToQuery(result)>
    <CFDUMP VAR="#result#">

Comment: Can you do a dump INSIDE the ArrayOfStructuresToQuery function to see what the incoming array parameter contains?  FYI I used this function in my own CSV import initially and ended up moving to Apache CSVManager for performance and compatibility reasons.